# Random "The specified cell does not exist." error with GetCellData method (webtable) in qtp

Tags: qtp

I am using `GetCellData` method of `WebTable` object in qtp to fetch each cell value of a webtable which has multiple rows across multiple pages and write to datasheet. Below is the code that I am using:

```
For i = 2 to rowct
     For j = 1 to colct
        Datatable.Value(j+1,"sheet1") = trim(frame1.WebTable("table1" ).GetCellData(i,j))
    Next
Next
```

row and column counts are fetched before the for loops as shown below:

```
rowct = frame1.WebTable("table1").RowCount
colct = frame1.WebTable("table1").ColumnCount(1)
```

But sometimes, I get the following error for some cells and I can not see any pattern so far, which makes me think this is a random issue:

> ERROR: The specified cell does not exist."

Some more info:

1. Usually first row has this error:

   > Please enter a search.
2. The error is at cell level and not at webtable / row level. Although in most of the occasions, I see when there is such error with one cell, the entire table (as I am writing to datatable) has the same error.
3. When such error occurs, I have seen that number of rows fetched is greater than actual number of rows in webtable. That is, if there is one row in actual table, then my datatable has 5 rows (and so on). Again this is random.
4. `i = 2` in the for loop because I don't want the first row as it contains headers.

Been stuck on this for a while, any help is greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

Web tables may contain different number of cells per row, this is why `WebTable.ColumnCount` accepts a parameter (the row number).

Try this:

```
For i = 2 to frame1.WebTable("table1").RowCount
     For j = 1 to frame1.WebTable("table1").ColumnCount(i)
        Datatable.Value(j+1,"sheet1") = trim(frame1.WebTable("table1" ).GetCellData(i,j))
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. But in my case number of cells is static for each row.
Update on my issue-
I added some wait statements after clicking the webelement to arrive at the webtable and after that I haven't been able to reproduce this issue. This is not the right solution at least in my case as I need to fetch data from multiple webtables and for the time-being I have added many wait statements which seems to have resolved the issue.
Let me know if anyone can think of a better solution ! I am sure there is one !!